# how to treat special characters in variable names

Tags: node.js

I have a json which has the a particular format, I wanted to extract data from it, but it contains ':' in its key value which is giving error while printing

```
metadata:
   {
      'A:B':'string'
   }

I have tried to take it in another varibale stills it gives error: 

text='A'+':'+'B';
console.log(metadata.text);

//console.log(metadata.A:B);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `jsonVariableName["ObjectName"]` instead of `sonVariableName.ObjectName`

```
var metadata = {
      'A:B':'string'
 };
console.log(metadata["A:B"]);
```

*Also I found you mention code as:*
`metadata:{...}`
*Which I think will be:*
`metadata = {...}`